# OpenGL 3.2 w/ NSOpenGLView

Tags: objective-c, opengl-3, nsopenglview, nsopengl

How would I create a core profile in a custom implementation of NSOpenGLView? Which method should I override and what code should I put there?

So far I have this code:

```
// Header File
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface TCUOpenGLView : NSOpenGLView

@end

// Source File
#import "TCUOpenGLView.h"
#import <OpenGL/gl.h>

@implementation TCUOpenGLView

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glFlush();
}

@end
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apple has a sample code project called [GLEssentials](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/GLEssentials/Introduction/Intro.html) that shows exactly how to do this (note that it is a Mac OS X and iOS sample code project).

Essentially you will need to subclass NSOpenGLView (the NSGLView class in the sample code) and implement the awakeFromNib method using the following:

```
- (void) awakeFromNib
{   
    NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute attrs[] =
    {
        NSOpenGLPFADoubleBuffer,
        NSOpenGLPFADepthSize, 24,
        // Must specify the 3.2 Core Profile to use OpenGL 3.2
        NSOpenGLPFAOpenGLProfile,
        NSOpenGLProfileVersion3_2Core,
        0
    };

    NSOpenGLPixelFormat *pf = [[[NSOpenGLPixelFormat alloc] initWithAttributes:attrs] autorelease];

    if (!pf)
    {
        NSLog(@"No OpenGL pixel format");
    }

    NSOpenGLContext* context = [[[NSOpenGLContext alloc] initWithFormat:pf shareContext:nil] autorelease];

    [self setPixelFormat:pf];

    [self setOpenGLContext:context];
}
```

Also remember that if you use any OpenGL API calls that have been removed from the 3.2 API your app will crash.  Here is a [PDF document](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec32.core.20090803.pdf) of the 3.2 spec so you can see the changes.